# your access token is expired, please renew it before submitting the request while adding user to group

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am using the below code to get the access token.

It is working for some time and then throwing the error like

> your access token is expired please renew it before submitting the request

```
public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUser()
{
    string strAutherizationString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthrizationURL"].ToString();
    string strResourceURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceURL"].ToString();
    string strDirectoryId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryId"].ToString();
    string strClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"].ToString();
    string strSecretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityKey"].ToString();

    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(strAutherizationString + strDirectoryId, false);
    try
    {
        if (TokenForUser == null)
        {                             

            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(strClientId, strSecretKey);
            AuthenticationResult userAuthnResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(strResourceURL, clientCred);
            TokenForUser = userAuthnResult.AccessToken;
            //Capturing the token for the user
            log.Info("GetTokenForUser()" + TokenForUser);                  

        }
        return TokenForUser;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Capturing the error log for the user token
        log.Error("GetTokenForUser()", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I imagine this comes up a bit later? Could you explain why you are clearing ADAL's token cache instead of utilizing it? You know you can just request for a token with client credentials and ADAL will return from cache if valid one exists?

Comment: Do you call GetTokenForUser function each time for making api calls or just store token  and used for api calls ?

Comment: @juunas, I have added that clear() method only after, I got this exception. as it is saying the token is expired every time, so I  am clearing the cache and trying to get a fresh token every time. But it is not happening.

Comment: @NanYu-MSFT, Below is code I am using to adding user to azure ad group. The AcquireTokenAsyncForUser() method will call the gettokenforuser method. This will be called two times when we retrive user from active directory and group from active directory.

Comment: @NanYu-MSFT,  ActiveDirectoryClient ADClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(GlobalConstants.ResourceUrl + AppModeConstants.TenantName),                                                                         async () => await AuthenitcationHelper.AcquireTokenAsyncForUser());
User ADUser = ADClient.Users.Where(user => user.Mail == UserEmailId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User; Group ADGroup = ADClient.Groups.Where(group => group.ObjectId == GroupId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;

Comment: By the way, you set `TokenForUser` once and never set it to null. I would get rid of that variable entirely, and just use ADAL token cache.

Comment: @juuhnas, That is a global variable, My application is trying to get access token two times consequently. for the first time, I am getting the token and assigning to tokenforUser next time it will check for null, the inside of the code will not be executed for the second time.